# Problema con programa para escribir dígitos con un número intermedio específico

Tags: c++

Resulta que estoy haciendo un programa dónde se marca un número de turnos (n) y dos personas escriben números y pierde el primero que escriba un número tal que su dígito central no coincida con el del número anterior. (El primer número puede tener cualquier dígito central.) Si alguien escribe un número con un número par de dígitos, pierde de inmediato. Si después de escribir los 2º números no pierde nadie, la partida termina en empate.

El empate no me lo marca debidamente y no sé a qué se puede deber.

```
Entrada: 3
3 134 78345 333 6543456 999939999

Salida: B
Salida esperada: =
```

Adjunto mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int counter(int r) {
    int counter = 0;
    while (r > 0) {
        r /= 10;
        ++counter;
    }
    return counter;
}

int middle(int r) {
    for (int i = 0; i < counter(r)/2; ++i) {
        r /= 10;
    }
    return r%10;
}

int main() {
    int n, r, middlenum;
    int turn = 0;
    bool first = true;
    bool winner = false;
    cin >> n;
    while (not winner and turn < n*2) {
        cin >> r;
        if (counter(r)%2 == 0) winner = true;
        else if (first) {
            middlenum = middle(r);
            first = false;
        }
        else if (middle(r) != middlenum) {
            winner = true;
        }

        ++turn;
    }
    if (not winner) cout << '=' << endl;
    else if (turn%2 == 0) cout << 'A' << endl;
    else cout << 'B' << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para saber cuántos dígitos tiene un número puedes usar `log10`

```
int num_digitos = static_cast<int>(std::log10(numero)) + 1;
```

Lo que sí que no puedes hacer es esto:

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter(r)/2; ++i) {
    r /= 10;
}
```

El motivo es que en cada iteración estás evaluando un `r` distinto, ya que dentro del bucle divides `r` entre 10. O usas dos variables diferentes o precalculas `counter(r)/2`:

```
int stop = counter(r)/2;
for (int i = 0; i < stop; ++i) {
    r /= 10;
}
```

Con esto el programa ya funcionaría correctamente. Sin embargo tienes que tener cuidado con los rangos. El tipo `int` tiene 32 bits y, dado que tiene signo, el número más alto que es capaz de almacenar es 2^31.

Para sortear esta limitación, sopesa utilizar `std::string` en vez de `int`:

```
std::string numero;
std::cin >> numero;

bool tiene_numero_par_de_digitos = numero.length() % 2 == 0;

char digito_central = numero[numero.length()/2];
```